# Is it possible for a block run with dispatch_async on a global queue to execute on the main thread?

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-async

If I say that time to time can happen that main thread can be busy with some global_queue tasks?

For example. I have some task to perform and I use one of the following statements:

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0)) {
      // task 1
    }

// or

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_UTILITY, 0)) {
      // task 2
    }
```

Is it possible accidentally get this tasks on main thread? Or it is impossible because main thread is locked for global queues?
Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried it? BTW, this completely nullifies the concept of background tasks. Keep your main thread as free as possible. There can only run one thing on the main thread at a time. If it's working on some of your "background" stuff, it is blocked; it won't update the UI, it won't respond to input, and if taken too long, the app will get killed.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But if main thread is idle it can take task from global_queue?

Comment: I'd say this would be a huge bug in the implementation and won't happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you dispatch on the global queue, it will run on the global queue. If you dispatch to the main queue, it will run on the main queue. If you dispatch to a queue that you created yourself, it will run on that queue.

You asked "But if main thread is idle it can take task from global_queue". No, that would be completely missing the point. If the main queue is idle, then all CPUs are available to run background tasks, so your background threads run a bit faster. It would be pointless and wrong for the main queue to take a task from another queue.

Comment: You are making statements about the implementation of GCD that are not supported by the documentation and imply implementation details that could be changed at any time without warning.

Comment: @ipmcc, this is basic concurrency. gnasher is correct.

Comment: The GCD documentation never says that submitting a task to a background GCD queue won't cause your computer to burst into flames, either. It's understood.

Comment: The GCD docs never say that there's a 64 thread limit on pool width, but in practice there is, and people run afoul of it every day. The GCD docs never say that queues you create implicitly target the four global queues, but in practice, they do. I agree that, in practice, the main thread does not get used to service other queues. I'm simply suggesting that folks take the documentation and API at face value and not make assumptions about the implementation.

Comment: @ipmcc The docs say that you get a concurrent queue, and the global queue is specified as a serial queue.

Answer (score 1):

In practice, that should not happen, however when you get a queue by specifying a QOS class, which queue you get is, strictly speaking, an implementation detail, and you shouldn't rely on it being a specific queue (or not a specific queue.) Furthermore, which threads any given queue uses to satisfy work enqueued to it is *also* an implementation detail.

But in practice, no, I would not expect to see work enqueued with `QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND` or `QOS_CLASS_UTILITY` being executed on the main thread.

If you want to convince yourself, you can check whether the queue returned from `dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_UTILITY, 0) == dispatch_get_main_queue()` and similarly, within your work unit, you can check `[NSThread isMainThread]` to see if you are executing on the main thread.

Comment: Thank you, but can this happen with other QoS like QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED or QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACITVE?

Comment: That, I'm less sure about, but even if I had observed it happening, it would still be an implementation detail. :) Giving it a quick test, it looks like, no, blocks `dispatch_async`ed to `QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACTIVE` and `QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED` are not executed on the main thread.

Comment: dispatch_get_global_queue _always_ returns a global queue and nothing else. It would be totally messed up to return anything else.

Comment: The main queue is a global queue.

Comment: @ipmcc But the main queue is a serial queue and not a concurrent one, as guaranteed by the docs.